# how to get the max of each column from an 2d array + index of the max value

Tags: python, arrays

I have for example

```
A = [[1 2 3 4 5]
     [2 4 5 8 7]
     [9 8 4 5 2]
     [1 2 4 7 2]
     [5 9 8 7 6]
     [1 2 5 4 3]]
```

So the shape of A = (5,6)
What I want is now the max of each column and return the result as eg:

`A = [[9 9 8 8 7]]` with as shape (5,1)

And at the same time I would like to receive the index of the max value from each column.

Is this possible? I don't find immediatly the sollution within the np.array basic doc.

Comment: question has nothing to do with `neural-network` of `jupyter-notebook` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed)...

Answer (score 4):

You could use [`ndarray.max()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.max.html).

The `axis` keyword argument describes what axis you want to find the maximum along.

`keepdims=True` lets you keep the input's dimensions.

To get the indizes of the maxima in the columns, you can use the [`ndarray.argmax()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.argmax.html) function.
You can also pass the `axis` argument ot this function, but there is no keepdims option.

In both commands `axis=0` describes the columns, `axis=1` describes the rows.
The standard value `axis=None` would search the maximum in the entire flattened array.

Example:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.asarray(
    [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
     [2, 4, 5, 8, 7],
     [9, 8, 4, 5, 2],
     [1, 2, 4, 7, 2],
     [5, 9, 8, 7, 6],
     [1, 2, 5, 4, 3]])
print(A)

max = A.max(axis=0, keepdims=True)
max_index = A.argmax(axis=0)

print('Max:', max)
print('Max Index:', max_index)
```

This prints:

```
[[1 2 3 4 5]
 [2 4 5 8 7]
 [9 8 4 5 2]
 [1 2 4 7 2]
 [5 9 8 7 6]
 [1 2 5 4 3]]
Max: [[9 9 8 8 7]]
Max Index: [2 4 4 1 1]
```

Comment: "axis=0 describes the columns, axis=1 describes the rows". I disagree, and stating it this way is very confusing. axis=0 refers to rows, and 1 to columns. But when we take the Max along the axis-0/rows we get columnwise maxima, and vice versa. See this image for understanding axis: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52468964/14998920.

Answer (score 1):

you can use numpy as well.

Example:

```
import numpy as np

A = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
 [2, 4, 5, 8, 7],
 [9, 8, 4, 5, 2],
 [1, 2, 4, 7, 2],
 [5, 9, 8, 7, 6],
 [1, 2, 5, 4, 3]]

print(A)

A=np.array(A)

print(A.max(axis=0))
```

Comment: And is it possible to keep the original indexes of my max values. EG: as index for the first 9 I would not have index 0 but index 2 ?

Comment: print(A.argmax(axis=0))

above line will give you max value indexes now you can combine both