# Finding median of each column in a matrix

Tags: python

Is there a way to find the median of each column in a ndarray. I tried the dumbest method using dual loop over each row to get the element column-wise and perform statstics.median on that and store it in a list.

But, as the dimensionality of the matrix grows, the time complexity will shoot up as well. Does Python have a better way to solve this?

```
arr = np.array([[1, 2, 3],[2,3,4],[3,4,5]])
print(arr)
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [2, 3, 4],
       [3, 4, 5]])
```

Expected output:

```
2,3,4
```

Comment: since you are using numpy, isn't it just ```np.median(arr,axis=1)```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I got one more question elated to np.median(). Say i have `arr = np.array([[1, 2, 3],[2,4,8],[3,4,5]])
arr

array([[1, 2, 3],
       [2, 4, 8],
       [3, 4, 5]])`
Then `np.median(arr,axis=0)` is returning `array([2., 4., 5.])` while the last element should have been 4. But when I use `statistics.median(arr[2])`, it indeed returns a 4, as expected. Is there a difefrence in the way np.median and statistics.median work?

Comment: i don't get why ```np.median(np.array([[1, 2, 3],[2,4,8],[3,4,5]]) , axis = 0)``` should give ```2,4,4``` . you are taking column medians

Comment: Initially, you said axis=1 so I thought it's for columns and 0 is for rows. But again, thanks a lot for providing info on np.median(). I now understand how it's working :)

Comment: @TheOwl I think you are getting confused by the axis kwarg, maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17079279/how-is-axis-indexed-in-numpys-array) will help.

Comment: arh i see. sorry, i read too quickly, "using dual loop over each row", and thought you wanted the row median. so it is axis = 0 for column, axis = 1 for row

Comment: Thank you guys for the documentation and explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

Use numpy.median() across columns.

```
arr = np.array([[1, 2, 3],[2,3,4],[3,4,5]])
print(arr)
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [2, 3, 4],
       [3, 4, 5]])

np.median(arr,axis=1)
```